# in Excel I want to convert integers to hours and minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a large spreadsheet ( >2000 observations) in which one column contains integers which represent a number of minutes (e.g. 43).
I have added up the numbers using SUM function.
I now want to convert this result into hours and minutes.
(I don't want to convert each single entry in hours/minutes, only the sum.)
Is there a function, or other technique, to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a formula like

```
=A1/(60*24)
```

and format the result with custom format

```
[hh]:mm
```

which will show hours greater than 24.